Nearest-Neighbor Depth Optimal Clifford Circuits
I am interested in the best state-of-the-art implementations for Clifford circuit compilation. In particular, I am interested optimizing the depth of nearest-neighbor $d$-dimensional Clifford Circuits. We can assume that we have any of the usual representations of a Clifford circuit (tableau/symplectic form, circuit w gates, etc.) to work with.
Here is what I am aware of:

"Hadamard-free circuits expose the structure of the Clifford group" gives a $9n$-depth decomposition of $n$-qubit Clifford unitaries on nearest neighbor architectures in 1D (although I don't know of an existing code implementation). AFAIK, this $9n$ is the current best.

Using mid-circuit measurements, it's possible to perform Clifford transformations in $O(1)$ depth assuming at least 2D nearest-neighbor connectivity (but, if possible, I would like to stick to the standard circuit model with no dynamic control.)


Any references/starting points in this area would be of great help!

https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.16195 achieves 7n instead of 9n on LNN.
